# Java code to run a shell script which in turn runs another script

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, processbuilder

I have gone through various similar questions asked in this forum or in the web in general but none matched my situation explained below. Basically I need to run a shell script from Java. Below is my code:

**In $HOME_FOLDER**

**run**

```
#!/bin/sh
----- various commands -----
java com.test.web.RestApplication --server.port=9090
```

**start.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $HOME_FOLDER
nohup ./run &
```

**stop.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill -f RestapiApplication
cd $HOME_FOLDER
rm -fr nohup.out
```

**In some other folder**

**RunShellScript.java**

```
public class RunShellScript
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            String enVar = System.getenv("HOME_FOLDER");
            String command = "";
            String option = args[0];
            switch(option){
                    case "start": command += enVar+"/start.sh";
                                    break;
                    case "stop": command += enVar+"/stop.sh";
            }
            try{
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c",command);
                    Process p = pb.start();
                    p.waitFor();
                    int shellExitStatus = p.exitValue();
                    System.out.println(shellExitStatus);
            }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

I was able to execute *stop.sh* (which kills the service and delete nohup.out) successfully from the code above but not *start.sh* (which basically runs my spring boot servce). Exit value is 0 on both the cases. When tried to run *start.sh* from the java code above does not even create *nohup.out* file that stores the output of my *run* script. *rd_start.sh* runs properly when run from command line (./start.sh). Any help in this regard? Thanks.

Comment: If these scripts generate any output, you need `pb.inheritIO();`.

Comment: Try to run RunShellScript with root user and check it creating a nohup.out file after running start.sh script